# ifstream from named pipe - check nonblocking if there is data

Tags: c++, linux, iostream, cin, peek

To check 'regular' `std::istream` if there is any pending data I can do just something like this:

```
bool has_pending_data(std::istream& s) {
  return s.peek() >= 0;
}
```

However, this is different for standard input and named pipes. If I do something like this:

```
if (has_pending_data(std::cin)) {
  // process incoming data
} else {
  // do some periodic tasks
}
```

the else branch is never reached since the execution will block on the `peek` function. Is there way to avoid this blocking for standerd input and named pipes?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when `std::cin` does not have character in the I/O buffer, the `peek` does not return with EOF, but wait till at least a character is written.

**This because the iostream library doesn't support the concept of non-blocking I/O**. I don't think there's anything in the C++ standard that does.

This code can help you to check existence of data in the stdin without blocking:

```
std::cin.seekg(0, std::cin.end);
int length = std::cin.tellg();
if (length < 0) return; //- no chars available
```

If stdin has some data - don't forget to set the position back to the beginning.

```
std::cin.seekg(0, std::cin.beg);
```

In alternative you can try to use the [select](https://linux.die.net/man/2/select) function. It's usually used for networking stuff, but it'll work just fine if you pass it the file descriptor for stdin.

Comment: select/poll was always an option, I was just asking if there is a way in vanilla cpp without linux stuff

Comment: Yes, I illustate to you the possible solution, with `seekg`, the select is only a last chance.

Comment: I tried to use your idea but it doesn't seem to work really. Looks like select is the only way here

Comment: I feared this happen, and this is the reason i append a second general purpose solution